# How do I compare the display layout of two pivot tables displayed next to each other

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

Below is the layout of the pivot tables but they are displayed next to each other:

Pivot table 1:

Product

- Product type 1

  -- Type 1

  -- Type 2

  -- Type 3
- Product Type 2

  -- Type 1

  -- Type 2

  -- Type 3

Pivot table 2:

Product

- Product type 1

  -- Type 1

  -- Type 2

  (How can i add a blank line here to match the layout of Pivot table 1?)
- Product Type 2

  -- Type 1

  -- Type 2

  (How can i add a blank line here to match the layout of Pivot table 1?)

How can i query the number of rows per Product Type and compare sizes, and add a blank row when required to match the layouts together?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Based on Excel 2007, copy your two PivotTables and Paste Special values somewhere convenient. You will lose the drill down facility and the ability to choose different views (without going back to your originals) but should be able to insert cells to align rows to suit.